# Dudas acerca del timestamp, php y el problema del 2038

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

Estoy realizando un aplicación con PHP que usa su función `date()`, ¿puedo pensar en que mi aplicación tenga una vida util más allá del 2038, rango superior de las fechas timestamp, la respuesta obvia para mi sería que no puesto que no existe una función que te devuelva la fecha actual, o cualquier otra, sin tener que recurrir a timestamp, ¿qué se debería hacer en ese caso?, ¿migrar la aplicación a otro lenguaje de servidor?, he leido que los equipos de 64 bits no tienen este problema, pero sigue siendo confuso, ¿luego esto no depende solo del motor de base de datos y el lenguaje de servidor, independientemente del equipo que los contenga?

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar mejor esto: **rango superior de las fechas timestamp**?

Comment: El tipo TIMESTAMP es un tipo entero que comprende la fecha y la hora con un rango efectivo desde '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC hasta '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.

Comment: Y ¿por qué no usar `DATETIME`? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html

Comment: ¿Como se crean registros con la fecha actual con ``DATETIME``?

Comment: `SELECT now();`

Comment: Y si por ejemplo quiero guardar una fecha futura, digamos... "fecha actual" + "1 mes"

Comment: Ya te toca leer la documentación de MySQL, la cual tiene funciones para modificar la fecha en función de sumarle o restarle, chécala vienen muchisimos métodos y alguno te servirá para eso

Comment: Lo haré, muchas gracias por la información :) te lo agradezco inmensamente

Comment: Ese límite sólo aplica a plataformas de 32 bits. Si tu servidor se ejecuta en una plataforma de 64 bits y usa una versión de PHP actualizada y compilada para 64 bits, no sufrirás del *bug* del 2038. Saludos

Comment: Para el caso del tipo de dato en la base de datos (MySQL y MariaDB), la sugerencia es que uses un tipo `DATE` o un tipo `DATETIME`, en vez del tipo `TIMESTAMP` el cual sufre de esta limitación. En PHP es recomendado el uso de la Clase [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php) en lugar de sólo `time()`. Con eso, seguramente tu aplicación sobreviva al problema del 2038, y ya sólo deberías preocuparte por el problema de que tu aplicación sobreviva hasta esa fecha. Más información en [2038.org](http://www.2038.org)

Comment: Todos respondieron, y comprendo porque hay que ayudar, pero, nadie se pregunta por qué quiere que su aplicación tal como está dure 20 años funcionando ? Probablemente en unos 10 ya sea lo suficientemente obsoleta para no poder usarse (en caso de no recibir actualizaciones)